# Problem with Ruby Gem and Sanitize

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sanitize

I'm trying to install the Ruby gem sanitize. I've already installed nokogiri:

```
>gem list nokogiri

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

nokogiri (1.4.0)
```

but when I try and install sanitize I get the following error:

```
>gem install rgrove-sanitize
ERROR:  Error installing rgrove-sanitize:
rgrove-sanitize requires nokogiri (~> 1.3.3, runtime)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rgrove-sanitize uses the [pessimistic operator](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74), which, in this case, means you need a Nokogiri version of 1.3.3 or greater, but less than 1.4 (which is what you have).   You need to install the correct version of Nokogiri:

```
>gem install --version "~> 1.3.3" nokogiri
```